# In kubernetes how can I tail the logs of future Job pods?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-jobs

I have a Job which creates a pod and I can tail its logs like this:

```bash
kubectl logs job/migration --follow
```

However, since it's a Job, the pod is expected to run, complete and then terminate. If I run the above command, I can see the logs for the last run of the pod but `kubectl` exits after printing out all of the logs, presumably because all of the pods its attempting to follow are terminated.

My Job has this annotation on it:

```yaml
  annotations:
    helm.sh/hook: post-install,post-upgrade
```

Such that when I run `helm install ...` it will cause the Job to create another pod, which again runs and terminates as expected.

My question is, is it possible to construct a `kubctl logs ...` command such that I can follow the logs of *future* migration pods? Such that I could have the command tailing in one terminal and then run `helm install` in another and then I would see the logs of the new pod in my terminal immediately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the solution is to use `xargs`.

To accomplish this we need to add `-o name` to get just the names of the existing pods and the new pods, then pipe it into xargs and follow the logs of those as they happen.

```bash
kubectl get pods -n example -l component=migration --watch -o name \
  | xargs kubectl logs -n example --follow
```

Refinements welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [stern](https://github.com/wercker/stern).

`stern --namespace example migration` or `stern --namespace -l component=migration` will show all logs of all present and future pods that have the word 'migration' in their name resp. the label.

The tool prints out all logs of all pods/containers, matching against (partial) names, so you could also use `stern --namespace example mig`. You can also include/exclude certain containers, run against all namespaces and get pretty good coloring schema to distinguish different pods/containers.