# Does "kubectl logs -f -l" follow newly created pod?

Tags: kubectl

`kubectl logs -f` with label seclection by `-l` like the followings:

```
$ kubectl logs -f -l 'role=job'
```

shows all pods matching the label-selection and keep the streamed logs.

What happens when a pod is newly created during the above kubectl logs -f runs?

Is the pod log also shown with the command or ignored?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the **-f(follow)** flag will continuously check and stream the logs of pods/containers. For example the command  `kubectl logs -f -l app=nginx --all-containers` streams the logs from all containers in pods defined by label app=nginx.  The `-follow` flag will continuously stream logs from any new pods that match the label selector specified with the `-l` flag. When you run this command, it starts streaming the logs from existing pods that match the label selector. However it keeps listening for new pods that are created and automatically starts streaming logs from those pods as well. This allows you to see the logs of newly created pods in real-time while the command is running.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I would like to know.

Comment: @FumiskyWells,  Happy to know you were able to understand the reference and can you please accept my answer, so that for the greater visibility of the community. [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is wrong, `--follow` controls if the logs should be streamed but does not watch for newly created pods.

Adapting the implementation from https://stackoverflow.com/a/73816530 gives us a solution:

```
kubectl -n example get pods -l role=job --watch -o name \
  | xargs kubectl -n example logs --follow
```

Comment: Oh, I see.  I rolled back.